# show all values in categorical variable

Tags: sas

The google search has been difficult for this.  I have two categorical variables, `age` and `months`, with 7 levels each.  for a few levels, say `age =7` and `month = 7` there is no value and when I use `proc sql` the intersections that do not have entries do not show, eg:

```
    age   month value
     1       1    4
     2       1    12
     3       1    5
      ....
     7       1    6
     ...
     1       7    8
      ....
     5       7    44
     6       7    5 
     THIS LINE DOESNT SHOW
```

what i want

```
   age   month value
     1       1    4
     2       1    12
     3       1    5
      ....
     7       1    6
     ...
     1       7    8
      ....
     5       7    44
     6       7    5 
     7       7    0
```

this happens a few times in the data, where tha last groups dont have value so they dont show, but I'd like them to for later purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some sample data:

```
data test;
do age=1 to 7;
    do month=1 to 12;
        value = ceil(10*ranuni(1));
        if ranuni(1) < .9 then
            output;
    end;
end;
run;
```

This leaves a few holes, notably, (1,1).

I would use a series of SQL statements to get the levels, cross join those, and then left join the values on, doing a coalesce to put 0 when missing.

```
proc sql;
create table ages as 
select distinct age from test;

create table months as 
select distinct month from test;

create table want as
select a.age,
       a.month,
       coalesce(b.value,0) as value
    from (
            select age, month from ages, months
         ) as a
      left join
         test as b
      on a.age = b.age
       and a.month = b.month;
quit;
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful.  this worked on a more simple example I had and it looks like it won't be hard to expand upon. Much appreciate

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options available, both seem to work on the premise of creating the master data and then merging it in. 
Another is to use a PRELOADFMT and FORMATs or CLASSDATA option.

And the last - but possibly the easiest, if you have all months in the data set and all ages, then use the SPARSE option within PROC FREQ. It creates all possible combinations.

```
proc freq data=have;
   table age*month /out = want SPARSE;
   weight value;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The group independent crossing of the classification variables requires a distinct selection of each level variable be `crossed join`ed with the others -- this forms a *hull* that can be left joined to the original data.  For the case of age*month having more than one item you need to determine if you want

- rows with repeated age and month and original value
- rows with distinct age and month with either

  - aggregate function to summarize the values, or
  - an indication of too many values

```
data have;
input age   month value;
datalines;
     1       1    4
     2       1    12
     3       1    5
     7       1    6
     1       7    8
     5       7    44
     6       7    5 
     8       8    1
     8       8    11
run;

proc sql;
  create table want1(label="Original class combos including duplicates and zeros for absent cross joins")
  as
  select 
    allAges.age
  , allMonths.month
  , coalesce(have.value,0) as value
  from
    (select distinct age from have) as allAges
  cross join
    (select distinct month from have) as allMonths
  left join
    have
  on 
    have.age = allAges.age and have.month = allMonths.month
  order by 
    allMonths.month, allAges.age
  ;
quit;
```

And a slight variation that marks duplicated class crossings

```
proc format;
  value S_V_V .t = 'Too many source values'; /* single valued value */
quit;

proc sql;
  create table want2(label="Distinct class combos allowing only one contributor to value, or defaulting to zero when none")
  as
  select distinct
    allAges.age
  , allMonths.month
  , case 
      when count(*) = 1 then coalesce(have.value,0)
      else .t
    end as value format=S_V_V.
  , count(*) as dup_check
  from
    (select distinct age from have) as allAges
  cross join
    (select distinct month from have) as allMonths
  left join
    have
  on 
    have.age = allAges.age and have.month = allMonths.month
  group by
    allMonths.month, allAges.age
  order by 
    allMonths.month, allAges.age
  ;
quit;
```

This type of processing can also be done in Proc TABULATE using the CLASSDATA= option.